# Можно ли производить поиск документов в коллекции MongoDB, если поля, по которым необходимо производить поиск, заданы с помощью списка?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

У меня есть некоторая функция, которая получает на вход название базы данных, коллекции и список полей, по которым необходимо делать поиск. Может быть, существует какой-то оператор, или как-то по другому можно передать список в db.collection.find(), чтобы можно было динамически определять поля для поиска?

Comment: Что в твоем понятии "список", относительно языка JS? Сам `find()` может выполнять поиск документа по нескольким полям... Какой "поисковый" объект ему дадут - по такому и будет искать... Приведи примеры того что ты собрался делать, может так будет более понятнее.